# Using Joins, Uniq and Group_by_month(:created_at)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, group-by, uniq

Hi so i am writing down the question again

so i have a 3 models 'User' 'Companion' 'Task'

and

```
User. has_many: companions, has_many: tasks
Companion: belongs_to: user
Task: belongs_to: user
```

and the datas what i need is a monthly data of User, and User who has Companions, then finally who has ordered a Task

so  i was trying to use this codes

```
User.group_by_month(:created_at).count
```

Untill here i was able to have the datas what i was thinking

```
 User.joins(:companions).uniq.group_by_month(:created_at).count
```

and i the monthly counted numbers of users who has companions but it doesn't work at all

then i also need to join a 'Task' to find out which user has a companion and also ordered a tasks

so the result what i would like to see is

Count User monthly registered

```
Aug, 2020 = > 300
```

Users who has companion

```
 Aug, 2020 = > 150
```

Users who has companion and ordered a task

```
 Aug, 2020 = > 75
```

I need uniq numbers User who has Companion, and User who has Companion and also Ordered a task

Comment: `but it doesn't work at all` => Elaborate on this please. What is the error that you get?

Comment: ah  i ve solve them with using distinct, instead of uniq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Uniq` works on arrays. For a `collection of records` you can use `distinct`.

Check: https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct

That means that you can use:

```
User.joins(:companions).distinct.group_by_month(:created_at).count
```